# Argument palette not working in ggcorr - GGally?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally

I would like to use the `ggcorr` function from `GGally` with the `RdBu` palette from [`RColorBrewer`](https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/top-r-color-palettes-to-know-for-great-data-visualization/) like demonstrated [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggally-r-package-extension-to-ggplot2-for-correlation-matrix-and-survival-plots-r-software-and-data-visualization). But it seems that non of the palettes seems to work. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
devtools::install_github("ggobi/ggally")
library(GGally)
library(RColorBrewer)
df <- mtcars[, c(1,3,4,5,6,7)]
ggcorr(df, label = TRUE)
```

[image]

```r
ggcorr(df, palette = "RdBu", label = TRUE)
```

[image]

```r
ggcorr(df, palette = "RdYlGn", label = TRUE)
```

[image]

```r
ggcorr(df, palette = "Set1", label = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

As you can see, I tried some palettes but every time the colors are the same. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to use a `palette` in `ggcorr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we check the source code, `nbreaks` not having a NULL value is needed for evaluation

```
> ggcorr
function (data, method = c("pairwise", "pearson"), cor_matrix = NULL, 
    nbreaks = NULL, digits = 2, name = "", low = "#3B9AB2", mid = "#EEEEEE", 
    high = "#F21A00", midpoint = 0, palette = NULL, geom = "tile", 
    min_size = 2, max_size = 6, label = FALSE, label_alpha = FALSE, 
    label_color = "black", label_round = 1, label_size = 4, limits = c(-1, 
        1), drop = is.null(limits) || identical(limits, FALSE), 
    layout.exp = 0, legend.position = "right", legend.size = 9, 
    ...) 
{
..
..
if (!is.null(nbreaks)) {
        x = seq(-1, 1, length.out = nbreaks + 1)
        if (!nbreaks%%2) {
            x = sort(c(x, 0))
        }
        m$breaks = cut(m$coefficient, breaks = unique(x), include.lowest = TRUE, 
            dig.lab = digits)
    }
..
..
 if (geom == "tile") {
        if (is.null(nbreaks)) {
            p = p + geom_tile(aes(fill = coefficient), color = "white")
        }
        else {
            p = p + geom_tile(aes(fill = breaks), color = "white")
        }
        if (is.null(nbreaks) && !is.null(limits)) {
            p = p + scale_fill_gradient2(name, low = low, mid = mid, 
                high = high, midpoint = midpoint, limits = limits)
        }
        else if (is.null(nbreaks)) {
            p = p + scale_fill_gradient2(name, low = low, mid = mid, 
                high = high, midpoint = midpoint)
        }
        else if (is.null(palette)) {
            x = colorRampPalette(c(low, mid, high))(length(levels(m$breaks)))
            p = p + scale_fill_manual(name, values = x, drop = drop)
        }
        else {
            p = p + scale_fill_brewer(name, palette = palette, 
                drop = drop)
        }
..

}
```

Also it is specified in documentation

> nbreaks - the number of breaks to apply to the correlation coefficients, which results in a categorical color scale.

> if nbreaks is used, a ColorBrewer palette to use instead of the colors specified by low, mid and high. Defaults to NULL.

Therefore, we may specify the `nbreaks`

```
ggcorr(df, palette = "RdYlGn", label = TRUE, nbreaks = 5)
```

-output

[image]

```
ggcorr(df, palette = "Set1", label = TRUE, nbreaks = 5)
```

-output
[image]

Comment: Aah great @akrun, thank you! It is nice that the [website](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggally-r-package-extension-to-ggplot2-for-correlation-matrix-and-survival-plots-r-software-and-data-visualization) is showing a output without using `nbreaks`.

Comment: @Quinten maybe it got updated with an earlier version of the package